# Wordpress doesn't show part of the css on mobile

Tags: css, wordpress

I've built my own WordPress theme, and everything went smoothly, until I put it online and looked at it on my phone. Apperently only a part of my css doesn't show. It is specifically the css I use to modify the look of the forms from the plugin "Ninja Forms".

I've added css classes to the form elements through the plugin and used them to modify the look of the forms in the css.

It works fine on desktop (Windows computer, Chrome and Edge browsers, but not on my phone (iPhone, Safari browser). I thought it might be Safari that was the problem, but the css works on my iPad in Safari...

Any ideas to what could be the problem?

Below is the used CSS for the forms.

```css
#newsletter-form, #contact-form {
    width: 30%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#newsletter-form {
    padding: 100px 0 50px 0;
}

#contact-form {
    padding: 50px 0 100px 0;
}

#contact-form h3, #newsletter-form h3 {
    font-size: 35px;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.form-contact-name-wrap, .form-newsletter-name-wrap {
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
}


.form-contact-name, .form-newsletter-name {
    border: 2px solid rgba(215,134,0,0.5);
}

.field-wrap div input, .field-wrap textarea {
    height: 35px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.form-contact-email, .form-newsletter-email {
    border: 2px solid rgba(215,134,0,0.5);
}

.form-contact-message, .form-newsletter-message {
    border: 2px solid rgba(215,134,0,0.5);
}

.form-contact-submit-wrap, .form-newsletter-submit-wrap {
    background: #D78600;
    color: white;
    border: 2px solid #9A6000;
    height: 40px;
    width: 120px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.form-contact-submit-wrap:hover, .form-newsletter-submit-wrap:hover {
    background-color: #9A6000;
}
```

Comment: Please specify your problem more detail. It'd be great if you upload its screen shot too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question and forgot to post it, but better late than never, right? xD

The issue was the cashe on my iPhone. Everything worked like it should after I deleted all of my browser data on my iPhone.

So much data deleted just to get a test website working properly on my own phone...